# Selecting rows from two tables MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables - player, which stores players data, and similar table team.
I want to select from these two tables name and surname of player and name of team to which one he belongs. I used this query:

```
SELECT player.name, player.surname,
   team.name AS teamname 
FROM player, team 
WHERE player.id_player=team.id_team
```

But as result i only have only one player from each team, and of course i want a full list of players with names of team.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Can you provide the schema for these two tables?

Comment: Player has id_player, name, surname, and team_id_team. Team has id_team and name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to join on the team id.  I am guessing something similar to this will work:

```
SELECT p.name, p.surname, t.name AS teamname 
FROM player p JOIN
     team t
     ON p.team_id_team = t.id_team ;
----------^ Note the change here
```

Also:

- Learn proper `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.
- If you have players without a valid team, then use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: Good catch on the error in the join condition. Based on the schema provided in the comment, it certainly seems you have the correct answer.

Comment: With this query i have a valid teams, left join dont work, whats the difference?

Answer (score 2):

You must use JOIN to "connect" the tables. With "WHERE" you only can exclude rows;

```
SELECT
  p.name,
  p.surname,
  t.name AS teamname 
FROM player p
LEFT JOIN team t ON p.id_player = t.id_team ;
```

Comment: this query shows wrong names of teams, and when it runs out of teamnames shows null, Grodon Linoff's answer works well

Comment: @Janusz Bieraszewski this is because there is typo in your query and author of this answer just copy it

Comment: @Evgeny - Yes i have seen the difference in the field names, but i canz see othe relations

Comment: This is because the join condition is incorrect.  I understand the answer, but not the upvotes.

Comment: @Janusz Bieraszewski - if you post your Table schema i can correct my answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use `left join`:

```
SELECT p.name, p.surname,
   t.name AS teamname 
FROM player p
left join team t on t.id_team=p.id_team
```